# Sorting arrays of structures in CUDA

Tags: sorting, struct, cuda

I have a laptop with an NVIDIA GT750M 4Gb (compute capability 3.0) graphics card. I need to sort an array of structures on CUDA (about 3 × 10^7 elements). But I cannot figure out how, since I do not have enough experience in CUDA. When using `thrust::sort` I get strange results (it takes a few tens of minutes, while `std::sort` takes `1` minute).

```
struct MyStruct
{
    float key;
    float a;
    float b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    bool flag;
}
bool minCompare(const MyStruct lhs, const MyStruct rhs)
{
    return lhs.key < rhs.key;
}
```

Comment: This post [Sorting objects with Thrust CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282039/sorting-objects-with-thrust-cuda) may already contain some useful information. I'm afraid that the slowness is related to the fact that you are using Arrays of Structs and not Structs of Arrays which as to do with non-optimal global memory accesses.

Comment: Tens of minutes sounds like something is broken.  I ran a quick test using 10,000,000 of your `MyStruct` elements, it took only a few seconds to sort.  Here's the [test case](http://pastebin.com/eAYkJbqv).  Unless you provide your code and test case, as I have, I don't think anyone can help you beyond JackOLantern's link.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Robert Crovella has pointed out in his comment, tents of minutes most likely means that you are doing something wrong. I'm providing an example below in which I compare the performance of sorting an Array of Structures (AoS) and a Structure of Arrays (SoA) using `thrust::sort` and `thrust::sort_by_key`. I'm running on a laptop GeForce GT 540M and compiling with CUDA 5.5, so you have a more powerful card than mine. For `100000` elements the execution time is of the order of seconds in both cases. As I pointed out in my comment, the first case is more demanding in terms of computation time (`1675ms`) than the second (`668.9ms`).

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\sort.h>

struct MyStruct1
{
    int key;
    int value1;
    int value2;
};

struct MyStruct2
{
    int N;
    int* key;
    int* value1;
    int* value2;

    MyStruct2(int N_) {
        N = N_;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&key,N*sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&value1,N*sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&value2,N*sizeof(int));
    }

};

__host__ __device__ bool operator<(const MyStruct1 &lhs, const MyStruct1 &rhs) { return (lhs.key < rhs.key); };

void main(void)
{
    const int N = 10000;

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;

    /*******************************/
    /* SORTING ARRAY OF STRUCTURES */
    /*******************************/
    thrust::host_vector<MyStruct1> h_struct1(N);
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        MyStruct1 s;
        s.key       = rand()*255;
        s.value1    = rand()*255;
        s.value2    = rand()*255;
        h_struct1[i]    = s;
    }
    thrust::device_vector<MyStruct1> d_struct(h_struct1);

cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

thrust::sort(d_struct.begin(), d_struct.end());

cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
printf("Sorting array of structs - elapsed time:  %3.1f ms \n", time);  

h_struct1 = d_struct;

//for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
//{
//  MyStruct1 s = h_struct1[i];
//  printf("key %i value1 %i value2 %i\n",s.key,s.value1,s.value2);
//}
//printf("\n\n");

/*******************************/
/* SORTING STRUCTURES OF ARRAYS*/
/*******************************/

MyStruct2 d_struct2(N);
thrust::host_vector<int> h_temp_key(N);
thrust::host_vector<int> h_temp_value1(N);
thrust::host_vector<int> h_temp_value2(N);

//for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
//{
//  h_temp_key[i]       = rand()*255;
//  h_temp_value1[i]    = rand()*255;
//  h_temp_value2[i]    = rand()*255;
//  printf("Original data - key %i value1 %i value2 %i\n",h_temp_key[i],h_temp_value1[i],h_temp_value2[i]);
//}
//printf("\n\n");

cudaMemcpy(d_struct2.key,h_temp_key.data(),N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_struct2.value1,h_temp_value1.data(),N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_struct2.value2,h_temp_value2.data(),N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// wrap raw pointers with device pointers 
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr_key     = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_struct2.key);
thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr_value1  = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_struct2.value1);
thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr_value2  = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_struct2.value2);

thrust::device_vector<int> d_indices(N);
thrust::sequence(d_indices.begin(), d_indices.end(), 0, 1);

// first sort the keys and indices by the keys
thrust::sort_by_key(dev_ptr_key, dev_ptr_key + N, d_indices.begin());

// Now reorder the ID arrays using the sorted indices
thrust::gather(d_indices.begin(), d_indices.end(), dev_ptr_value1, dev_ptr_value1);
thrust::gather(d_indices.begin(), d_indices.end(), dev_ptr_value2, dev_ptr_value2);

cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
printf("Sorting struct of arrays - elapsed time:  %3.1f ms \n", time);  

cudaMemcpy(h_temp_key.data(),d_struct2.key,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(h_temp_value1.data(),d_struct2.value1,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(h_temp_value2.data(),d_struct2.value2,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

//for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) printf("Ordered data - key %i value1 %i value2 %i\n",h_temp_key[i],h_temp_value1[i],h_temp_value2[i]);
//printf("\n\n");

getchar();

}
```

For the sake of simplicity, I have skipped adding proper CUDA error check in the sense of [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).

Comment: Big thanks to everyone for examples! I almost understood. It was necessary to prescribe some kind settings in Visual Studio 2010 because if to take example of a project from the SDK and copy the code there, then everything works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone's still looking, if you decide to use Thrust libraries, you can make a zip iterator of tuples from the structure of arrays that you want to sort, and pass this iterator to `thrust::sort_by_key()` like so:

```
void sort() {
   const int N = 6;
   int  *keys = new  int[N]; // = { 1,   4,   2,   8,   5,   7};
   char *vals = new char[N]; // = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
   int  *addr = new  int[N]; // = { 1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6};
   keys[0]=1; keys[1]=4; keys[2]=2; keys[3]=8; keys[4]=5; keys[5]=7;
   vals[0]='a'; vals[1]='b'; vals[2]='c'; vals[3]='d'; vals[4]='e'; vals[5]='f';
   addr[0]=1; addr[1]=2; addr[2]=3; addr[3]=4; addr[4]=5; addr[5]=6;

   int *d_keys, *d_addr;
   char *d_vals;
   CUDA_SAFE(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_keys, N * sizeof(int)));
   CUDA_SAFE(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_addr, N * sizeof(int)));
   CUDA_SAFE(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_vals, N * sizeof(char)));
   CUDA_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(d_keys, keys, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
   CUDA_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(d_vals, vals, N * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
   CUDA_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(d_addr, addr, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

   auto it = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_vals, d_addr));

   thrust::sort_by_key(thrust::device, d_keys, d_keys+N, it);

   CUDA_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(keys, d_keys, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
   CUDA_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(vals, d_vals, N * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
   CUDA_SAFE(cudaMemcpy(addr, d_addr, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

   printf("Keys: "); for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d ", keys[i]); printf("\n");
   printf("Vals: "); for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%c ", vals[i]); printf("\n");
   printf("Addr: "); for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d ", addr[i]); printf("\n");
}
```

I have excluded the headers and checks for brevity.