# Thrust::sort slow for array of structs of size 300k in GTX960M

Tags: opengl, cuda, thrust

I'm currently working on a GPU rendering algorithm in which I need to sort an array of this struct:

```
struct RadiosityData {
    vec4 emission;
    vec4 radiosity;
    float nPixLight;
    float nPixCam;
    float __padding[2];
};
```

I am using the following code to sort the array:

```
thrust::device_ptr<RadiosityData> dev_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(GPUpointer_ssbo);
thrust::sort(dev_ptr, dev_ptr + N);
```

where GPUpointer_ssbo is a GPU pointer coming from cudaOpenGL interop, N is equal to ~300k. The comparison is done with:

```
__host__ __device__ bool operator<(const RadiosityData& lhs, const RadiosityData& rhs) { return (lhs.nPixCam > rhs.nPixCam); };
```

The sorting is very slow on my GTX960M: without sorting, my aplication is doing ~10ms per frame, while with sorting it is taking around 35ms. This means the sorting is taking ~25ms. I am measuring the exec time with VS-NSIGHT

I am aware that this problem can be a GPU sync problem since I am doing OpenGL operations prior to calling thrust. Nevertheless, I am not convinced by this argument, because if I use the unsorted array to display data with OpenGL, it still takes 10ms total, which means that there is no sync problems with the OpenGL code itself.

Is this performance expected for such "small" array? Is there a better GPU sorting algorithm available for this kind of problem?

------------EDIT:
I'm compiling in release with the default VS2019 CUDA command, which is:

Driver API (NVCC Compilation Type is .cubin, .gpu, or .ptx)
set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu        --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -o x64\Release\sortBufferCUDA.cu.obj "C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\RealTimeDiffuseIlumination\OpenGL-avanzado\sortBufferCUDA.cu"

Runtime API (NVCC Compilation Type is hybrid object or .c file)
set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu        --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static      -Xcompiler "/EHsc  /nologo  /Fd /FS /Zi   " -o x64\Release\sortBufferCUDA.cu.obj "C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\RealTimeDiffuseIlumination\OpenGL-avanzado\sortBufferCUDA.cu"

--------------EDIT 2:

The following is a minimal working example:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>


struct RadiosityData {
    float emission[4];
    float radiosity[4];
    float nPixLight;
    float nPixCam;
    float __padding[2];
};

extern "C" void CUDAsort();

__host__ __device__ bool operator<(const RadiosityData& lhs, const RadiosityData& rhs) { return (lhs.nPixCam > rhs.nPixCam); };

int pri = 1;

thrust::device_vector<RadiosityData> dev;

void CUDAsort() {
    if (pri == 1) {
        pri = 0;
        dev.resize(300000);

    }
    thrust::sort(dev.begin(), dev.end());

}

int main()
{
    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;


    while (true) {
        cudaEventCreate(&start);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop);
        cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
        CUDAsort();

        cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
        printf("Time to generate:  %3.1f ms \n", time);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can sort (using thrust) 300k of those struct in ~4.4ms on my GTX960.  A GTX960 will be a bit faster than a 960M, I'd be surprised if it were 5x faster.  You might be measuring other things besides the sort, also.  Make sure to compile a release project, not a debug project.  Even on a lowly GT640 it only takes ~15ms.

Comment: I also tried it on a GTX2080Ti and it takes around 10ms... I am measuring FPS with NSIGHT, basically comment and uncomment the thrust::sort makes the 25ms difference...

Comment: I just updated the post with the compilation command I use. Do you see any problem there?

Comment: No I don't.  I didn't really expect it to be a release/debug issue because when I compile in debug mode my sort time jumps up to ~350ms.  FWIW the code you have shown doesn't make sense to me.  But I'm not going to go down that avenue since you've shown nothing like a [mcve].

Comment: Haha, sorry, I know I didn't, but that is because my code is too complex to post it right here. I may work on a MRE and come back. I just wanted to be sure that I had a problem, and that it was not the expected performance for Thrust. You say it doesn't make sense because I haven't put the rest of the code, right? Or do you see something wrong with these few lines I showed?

Comment: For example, I don't understand this: `thrust::sort(dev_ptr, dev_ptr + N);`  It looks like it is missing the sort functor.  But whatever.  I don't know everything.  Maybe you have some magic going on.

Comment: operator< is declared in the same .cu file for the struct RadiosityData. I need to pass it as an argument?

Comment: At least this is what is done in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541503/sorting-arrays-of-structures-in-cuda

Comment: OK, understood.  It doesn't make any change to my timing.

Comment: I just updated the post with a working example, do you think you can try it? It takes 20ms in my GTX960M

Comment: Ok, I just simplified the code so it can be ran easier. It still takes 20ms, so I guess its just the expected performance for Thrust

Comment: If you change `float emission[4];
    float radiosity[4];` to `float4 emission; float4 radiosity;` it cuts the time almost in half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking thrust to move 48-byte structures around as it is sorting is certainly possible but possibly not the most efficient approach.

What we could try instead is:

1. pull the float values used for sorting out of the Array of Structures (AoS) into a `float` array
2. create a index array to go along with this  0 1 2 3...
3. sort_by_key the float values, carrying the integer indexes along
4. using the rearranged index array, do a single permuted copy of the AoS from input to output
5. copy the output array back over the input array, to simulate "in place" sorting

It looks like a lot of work, but it's actually a little bit quicker according to my testing:

```
$ cat t30.cu
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL
long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

struct RadiosityData {
#ifdef USE_VEC
 float4 emission;
 float4 radiosity;
#else
 float emission[4];
 float radiosity[4];
#endif
        float nPixLight;
 float nPixCam;
        float __padding[2];
};

__global__ void copyKernel(RadiosityData *d, float *f, int *i, int n){
 int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
 if (idx < n){
  f[idx] = d[idx].nPixCam;
  i[idx] = idx;}
}

__host__ __device__ bool operator<(const RadiosityData &lhs, const RadiosityData  &rhs) { return (lhs.nPixCam > rhs.nPixCam); };
struct my_sort_functor
{
 template <typename T1, typename T2>
 __host__ __device__ bool operator()(T1 lhs, T2 rhs) { return (lhs.nPixCam > rhs.nPixCam); };
};
const int N = 300000;
int main(){
 RadiosityData *GPUpointer_ssbo, *o;
 int sz = N*sizeof(RadiosityData);
 thrust::device_vector<RadiosityData> ii(N);
 GPUpointer_ssbo = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(ii.data());
 thrust::device_ptr<RadiosityData> dev_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(GPUpointer_ssbo);
//method 1: ordinary thrust sort
 long long dt = dtime_usec(0);
 thrust::sort(dev_ptr, dev_ptr+N);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 dt = dtime_usec(dt);
 std::cout << "ordinary sort time: " << dt/(float)USECPSEC << "s" << std::endl;
//method 2: reduced sort-and-copy
 cudaMalloc(&o, sz);
 thrust::device_ptr<RadiosityData> dev_optr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(o);
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {RadiosityData q{0}; q.nPixCam = rand(); ii[i] = q;}
 float *d;
 int *k;
 cudaMalloc(&d, N*sizeof(float));
 cudaMalloc(&k, N*sizeof(int));
 thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_kptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(k);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 dt = dtime_usec(0);
 copyKernel<<<(N+511)/512, 512>>>(GPUpointer_ssbo, d, k, N);
 thrust::sort_by_key(thrust::device, d, d+N, k);
 thrust::copy(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(dev_ptr, dev_kptr), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(dev_ptr, dev_kptr+N), dev_optr);
 cudaMemcpy(GPUpointer_ssbo, o, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 dt = dtime_usec(dt);
 std::cout << "sort+copy time: " << dt/(float)USECPSEC << "s" << std::endl;
}

$ nvcc -o t30 t30.cu -arch=sm_52
$ ./t30
ordinary sort time: 0.009527s
sort+copy time: 0.003143s
$ nvcc -o t30 t30.cu -arch=sm_52 -DUSE_VEC
$ ./t30
ordinary sort time: 0.004409s
sort+copy time: 0.002859s
$
```

(CUDA 10.1.105, GTX960, fedora core 29)

So we observe about a 50% or better speed-up with the improved method.

If you only wanted to return the top-M elements of the sort, with this deconstructed-copy method, we can make some further improvements, by reducing the size of the copy operations.  The full sort is done on the float quantities, but when it comes to copying the AoS results, only the top-M values are copied:

```
$ cat t30.cu
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL
long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

struct RadiosityData {
#ifdef USE_VEC
 float4 emission;
 float4 radiosity;
#else
 float emission[4];
 float radiosity[4];
#endif
        float nPixLight;
 float nPixCam;
        float __padding[2];
};

__global__ void copyKernel(RadiosityData *d, float *f, int *i, int n){
 int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
 if (idx < n){
  f[idx] = d[idx].nPixCam;
  i[idx] = idx;}
}

__host__ __device__ bool operator<(const RadiosityData &lhs, const RadiosityData  &rhs) { return (lhs.nPixCam > rhs.nPixCam); };
struct my_sort_functor
{
 template <typename T1, typename T2>
 __host__ __device__ bool operator()(T1 lhs, T2 rhs) { return (lhs.nPixCam > rhs.nPixCam); };
};
const int N = 300000;
const int M = 1000;  // identifies top-M values to be returned by sort
int main(){
 RadiosityData *GPUpointer_ssbo, *o;
 int sz = N*sizeof(RadiosityData);
 thrust::device_vector<RadiosityData> ii(N);
 GPUpointer_ssbo = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(ii.data());
 thrust::device_ptr<RadiosityData> dev_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(GPUpointer_ssbo);
//method 1: ordinary thrust sort
 long long dt = dtime_usec(0);
 thrust::sort(dev_ptr, dev_ptr+N);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 dt = dtime_usec(dt);
 std::cout << "ordinary sort time: " << dt/(float)USECPSEC << "s" << std::endl;
//method 2: reduced sort-and-copy
 cudaMalloc(&o, sz);
 thrust::device_ptr<RadiosityData> dev_optr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(o);
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {RadiosityData q{0}; q.nPixCam = rand(); ii[i] = q;}
 float *d;
 int *k;
 cudaMalloc(&d, N*sizeof(float));
 cudaMalloc(&k, N*sizeof(int));
 thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_kptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(k);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 dt = dtime_usec(0);
        copyKernel<<<(N+511)/512, 512>>>(GPUpointer_ssbo, d, k, N);
 thrust::sort_by_key(thrust::device, d, d+N, k);
 thrust::copy_n(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(dev_ptr, dev_kptr), M, dev_optr);
 cudaMemcpy(GPUpointer_ssbo, o, M*sizeof(RadiosityData), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 dt = dtime_usec(dt);
 std::cout << "sort+copy time: " << dt/(float)USECPSEC << "s" << std::endl;
}


$ nvcc -o t30 t30.cu -arch=sm_52 -lineinfo -DUSE_VEC
$ ./t30
ordinary sort time: 0.004425s
sort+copy time: 0.001042s
$
```

A few other notes:

1. It's also observed that the AoS is more efficiently handled by thrust when the 4-`float` quantities are represented with a vector type (`float4`) instead of a 4-element array.  I suspect that this allows the compiler to identify a more efficient structure copy method.
2. Also note that according to my testing, compiling for the correct GPU architecture (`sm_52` in my case) seems to make a small improvement.  YMMV.

I don't claim correctness for this code or any other code that I post. Anyone using any code I post does so at their own risk. I merely claim that I have attempted to address the questions in the original posting, and provide some explanation thereof. I am not claiming my code is defect-free, or that it is suitable for any particular purpose. Use it (or not) at your own risk.

Comment: fantastic summary!! thank you very much for taking the time to do this code. Your new approach is clear and, although more complex, looks very neat. I will try it ASAP. 

I have one last question. Due to the nature of the problem I am solving, I don't need the entire array to be sorted, but just to get the first M greatest values (with M=~1k, for example). Does thrust provide something similar to std::partial_sort ? This idea can even bring better performance to my code.

Comment: thrust doesn't have any algorithms for that

Comment: You could reduce the size of the copy operations in my example to copy only the first M elements, this should provide some benefit.  For example instead of `thrust::copy` use `thrust::copy_n` where you specify M for the n argument.  I've updated my answer to include this.